# Ordering conditionally - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I have been trying to do is to conditionally set the values by which to order my ng-repeat values.

What I tried to do is to take the conditional method used to add ng-classes like so:

```
ng-class="{'active':item.selected}"
```

and combine it with a date orderBy method:

```
ng-repeat="item in filterPosts | orderBy:['yyyy','mm','dd']"
```

which would result in either of the following, but unfortunately none of which work.

```
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: [{('yyyy','mm','dd'):(sortBy=='Recently Added')}]"
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: [{'yyyy':(sortBy=='Recently Added')}]"
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: [{'yyyy':sortBy=='Recently Added'}]"
```

The Recently Added string as seen above will be selected from a dropdown to select the filter options

**If SortBy = true**

```
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: [{'yyyy':sortBy}]"
```

Any ideas on how to make this work, or if this is possible?

**UPDATE**

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/11692/)

As you will see, it is not working.

if you uncomment this line:

```
<!--li ng-repeat="item in activities"> -->
```

and comment out this line:

```
<li class="item_wrap" ng-repeat="item in activities | orderBy: [{'yyyy':recent}]">
```

You will see the list items

Comment: It is just a string value. It will be selected from a dropdown to selectthe filter options

Comment: can u create a plunker ?

Comment: I will add one shortly

Comment: does you item has 'yyyy' propery?

Comment: An example has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your select must have ng-change directive to assign **sortBy** parameters. like below

```
<select ng-init="sortBy='+date'" ng-model="sortType" ng-change="sortBy= sortType=='Recently Added' ? '-date':sortType=='Name' ? '+name':'+date';">
     <option>Recently Added</option>
     <option>Name</option>
</select>
```

Then you repeater directive shoul be something like this

```
 ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sortBy:true"
```

Comment: This is actually a simple way of doing it. Thanks for the help